# ES6: Bind Click or OnChange Event in string literal

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there any way to bind click/onchange/event in es6 string literals.

Lets say I have on string literal:

```
function myTemplate() {
  let onClickHandler = function() { alert('Yes it works') }; 
  return `<button onclick="(onClickHandler)">Click Me</button>`;
}
```

I tried above and when check HTML is show me as:

```
<button onclick="(function () { [native code] })">Click Me</button>
```

On click is throws error as :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Can somebody help how can we achieve this?

Comment: Its probably better to return a new Element instead of a string.

Comment: Short answer is ... No

Comment: Returning element looks good idea but i am looking for string literal should get bind to some event

Comment: @PankajBadukale but onclick gets called in different context. Can't bind anything to a string which is what template literal returns

Comment: @charlietfl Ok. So can we able to bind it right context or somehow it should get fire. Like we use call, apply, bind for context passing we think of it later If we able to fire atleast click and function get invoke in any context that also OK

Comment: No. What would you `bind()` to?

Comment: Btw, the code you posted does not output `function () { [native code] }`. What did you really do?

Answer (score 1):

you cant bind an event to a string. 
what you can do is add a function call to the string and then when you attach the element  to the dom it will work.

ps

the function will need to be on the global scope(window),

and you don`t need es6 syntax for that

```js
function myTemplate() {
  window.onClickHandler = function() { alert('Yes it works') }; 
  return `<button onclick="onClickHandler()">Click Me</button>`;
}
document.body.innerHTML = myTemplate()
```

Comment: But he needs jQuery for that.

Comment: @amitWangner this will work of course but does really we expose our every javascript function to global scope(window) And we dont need jquery for this. I dont understand why you have added it.

Comment: @PankajBadukale that's your only choice using string html and `onclick`. Stop using `onclick` and use more modern unobtrusive event listeners and you don't have that problem

Comment: @alexP Not really... the button onclick has nothing to do with jQuery

Comment: @PankajBadukale because you build the element from the body and not with JavaScript then you cant put the function reference . so the object reference will be the window

Answer (score 1):

I think that's the better way for creating a DOM element:

```js
(function myTemplate() {
  let onClickHandler = function() { alert('Yes it works') };  
  var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  button.onclick = onClickHandler;
  button.innerHTML = 'Click Me';
  document.getElementById("button").append(button);
})();
```

```html
<div id="button"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think this is ES6 string literals

Comment: @PankajBadukale Why do you think you need a string literal?

Answer (score 0):

If you are completely stuck on needing an html string returned you could give it a timestamp based or UUID ID and add event listener to window that looks for that ID target

```js
function myTemplate() {
  let id = `myButton_${Date.now()}`;
  window.addEventListener('click', (evt)=> evt.target.id === id && console.log(evt.target));
  return `<button id="${id}">Click Me</button>`;
}

document.body.innerHTML = myTemplate();
```

Answer (score 0):

And just to expand a bit on Amit Wagner's answer:
If you want to add parameters to your function call, you can do so like this:

```
function myTemplate() {
  window.onClickHandler = function(resultVar) { alert('Yes it ' + resultVar) }; 
  const someVar = 'works';
  return `<button onclick="onClickHandler('${works}')">Click Me</button>`;
}
document.body.innerHTML = myTemplate();
```

Don't forget to add the single quotes. The 'someVar' variable is a string and within a template literal, it will not output the quotes.

If you want to pass the element as an input value, use this:

```
return `<button onclick="onClickHandler(this)">Click Me</button>`;
```